# Como pegar todos os valores do 'YamlDotNet' em 'Arquivo.yml'?

Tags: c#, json, .net, winforms, yaml

Estou trabalhando em um arquivo.yml e quero pegar todos os valores que contem nesse arquivo. Estou usando a referência [YamlDotNet.Serialization](http://YamlDotNet).

O que quero fazer, é pegar um determinado valor e exibir as propriedades desse determinado valor. Mas só que deserializando o "file.yml", obtenho um tipo de valor com formato de `Dictionary<object, object>`.

Abaixo, estou "deserializando o file.yml" e "serializando no file.json"

### YAML

```
groups:
  Default:
    default: true
    permissions:
    - essentials.kits.tools
    - essentials.kits.armor
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.sell
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.help.*
    - essentials.clearinventory
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.back.ondeath
    - essentials.delhome
    - essentials.home
    - essentials.home.bed
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.sethome.bed
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.signs.use.*
    - essentials.spawn
    inheritance:
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&7Peasent] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  Builder:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - essentials.gamemode
    - essentials.time
    - essentials.weather
    - essentials.time.set
    - essentials.bigtree
    - essentials.repair.*
    - essentials.workbench
    - essentials.break.bedrock
    - essentials.tp
    - worldedit.*
    inheritance:
    - default
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&6&lBuilder&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  VIP:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - essentials.gamemode
    - essentials.time
    - essentials.time.set
    - essentials.repair.*
    - essentials.tp
    - essentials.tphere
    inheritance:
    - default
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&6&lVIP&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  Donator:
    default: false
    permissions:
    inheritance:
    - vip
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&6&lDonator&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  Moderator:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - essentials.ban.*
    - essentials.tempban.*
    - essentials.kick.*
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.warp.list
    - essentials.sethome.others
    - essentials.home.others
    inheritance:
    - donator
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&cModerator&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  ModeratorPlus:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - essentials.gamemode.others
    - essentials.spawn.others
    - heads.*
    inheritance:
    - moderator
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&cModerator&c&l+&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  Admin:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - essentials.banip
    - essentials.unbanip
    - essentials.unban
    - essentials.exp.*
    - essentials.fly.*
    inheritance:
    - moderatorplus
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&2Solider] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  AdminPlus:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - worldedit.*
    inheritance:
    - admin
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&2ADMIN&2&l+&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  Co-Owner:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - essentials.*
    inheritance:
    - adminplus
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&b&lCO&r-&bOWNER&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  Owner:
    default: false
    permissions:
    - '*'
    - -vanish.*
    inheritance:
    - co-owner
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&b&lOWNER&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
  OP:
    default: false
    permissions:
    inheritance:
    - owner
    info:
      prefix: '&8[&e&lOP&8] '
      build: true
      suffix: ''
```

### Código

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GroupManager_JSon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getProperties();
        }

        public void getProperties()
        {
            // deserializando
            string path = "file.yml";
            var r = new StreamReader(path);
            var deserializer = new Deserializer();
            var yamlDynamic = deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(r);
            Dictionary<object, object> dic = new Dictionary<object, object>();

            var values = yamlDynamic.Values;
            dic = yamlDynamic;

            foreach (var item in dic.Values)
            {

            }

            // serializando
            JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
            var w = new StringWriter();
            js.Serialize(w, yamlDynamic);
            string jsonText = w.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText("file.json", jsonText);
        }
    }
}
```

Na deserialização da variável "yamlDynamic", percebi que o seu tipo é:

```
Dictionary<object, object>
```

E dentro de cada "Values" das "Keys" desse dicionário, parece conter mais:

```
Dictionary<object, object>
```

Como na foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só consigo puxar esses valores com uma variável `dynamic`, como na variável `values` acima. Como posso `deserializar` o tipo do `Dictionary<object, object>` para outro tipo? Porque eu quero puxar os tipos literalmente em não em tipos diversos, por exemplo, o `object` é um tipo diverso, não sei se ele é um `List<>` ou um `Dictionary<>`. Aqui eu só quero espalhar todos esses tipos de valores em uma `Classe`, ou formar uma variável única e dentro dessa variável, vários tipos. Nem que seja, um tipo grande como:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>> dicc = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>();
```

É só um exemplo.

O que importa para mim, é fugir do "object" sem precisar usar a variável `dynamic`. E por fim, puxar o tipo e trabalhar sobre esse tipo.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Para fazer o `Deserialize` para uma classe específica precisa de ter essa classe, caso contrário terá que trabalhar com `dynamic` porque o código não "conhece" o tipo. Tem alguma classe já criada?

Comment: Eu não tenho ainda a classe, porque conforme eu vou alterando as propriedades  do arquivo.yml, as propriedades da classe serão inúteis. E não sei como espalhar os valores assim :/

Comment: O processo que você está descrevendo para definir um tipo ao invés de object é exatamente o de criar uma classe que representa a estrutura para fazer a deserialização como disse o @JoãoMartins

Comment: Entendi, mas como monto a classe de acordo a estrutura? Eu depuro a variável JSON e vou vendo os tipos de valores que tem nela? Para criar os valores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Para deserializar com tipo definido precisa de uma classe

Abaixo uma sugestão baseada no que você postou. Se mudar o formato precisa adaptar a classe ou o alias de cada propriedade.

```
public partial class Security
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "groups")]
    public Groups Groups { get; set; }
}

public partial class Groups
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "Default")]
    public Admin Default { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "Builder")]
    public Admin Builder { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "VIP")]
    public Admin Vip { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "Donator")]
    public Admin Donator { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "Moderator")]
    public Admin Moderator { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "ModeratorPlus")]
    public Admin ModeratorPlus { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "Admin")]
    public Admin Admin { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "AdminPlus")]
    public Admin AdminPlus { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "Co-Owner")]
    public Admin CoOwner { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "Owner")]
    public Admin Owner { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "OP")]
    public Admin Op { get; set; }
}

public partial class Admin
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "default")]
    public bool Default { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "permissions")]
    public string[] Permissions { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "inheritance")]
    public string[] Inheritance { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "info")]
    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public partial class Info
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "prefix")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "build")]
    public bool Build { get; set; }

    [YamlMember(Alias = "suffix")]
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
}
```

Com a classe definida você pode fazer a deserialização especificando a classe:

```
string path = "file.yml";
Security security;
using (var r = new StreamReader(path)) {
   var deserializer = new Deserializer();
   security = deserializer.Deserialize<Security>(r);
}
```

Comment: Eu usei o YAML que você postou aqui no meu teste. Se ele mudou talvez tenha que adaptar.

Comment: ops, falha minha